# Jquery click event on a div tile not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery click event on a div tile not working. I do not want to manipulate CSS directly in jquery script

I created a tile with a simple div. I have four divs. Each div has a class "tiles. These 4 divs are in a outer bigger div but I guess that does not matter here. I added some query code to make sure that when i click on a tile, a new class "activeTiles" get added. In my css file, the tiles class has a background color "blue" and the activeTile class has background color "cyan". So the jquery code I wrote, adds the class "activeTile" so that the color changes for the tile. I am using "mousedown" event. However, the problem I face is that even though the new class gets added on clicking, the color of the tile does not change until I move the mouse out of the div area of the tile. So essentially, when i press mouse button and leave mouse button, in the console my log gets printed that event handler clicked. But the color of the tile is not changing until i move the mouse curosr out of the div. Can anyone tell why? here is my tile and activetile and jquery code.

```
.tiles {
color: white;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
/*margin: 0 auto;*/
background-color: #3399CC;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid #2F4F4F;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
/*text-align: center;*/
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 13;
font-weight: bold;
}



.activeTile {
background-color: cyan;
}
```

Here is the jquery function:

```
$(function() {
$(".tiles").on('mousedown',function() {
console.log("tile clicked")
$(".activeTile").removeClass("activeTile");
$(this).toggleClass("activeTile");
});
});
```

Comment: try click instead of mousedown- $(".tiles").on("click",function(){})

Comment: sorry friend, already tried it and it does not work.

Comment: can you make fiddle please?

Comment: how do i make fiddle?

Comment: Have you include https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js in your code. your code working perfect. https://jsfiddle.net/57qx6c6e/.

Comment: Make a demo in either jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com demonstrating ur problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mQnCBlgP33

Comment: i just did friends. thank you for help. waiting for a response.

Comment: If I am not wrong then u want to add activeclass onclick of tiles and remove from other tiles?isn't it?

Comment: yes debin your understanind is correct but as you can also see the endresult should be that once class is added color of activeTile class should show up but it does show up only after i move the cursor out of the div after the click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(".tiles").on('click', function() {
      $(".tiles").removeClass("activeTile");
      $(this).toggleClass("activeTile");
    });
```

css

```
.tiles:not(.activeTile):hover{background-color: #0047AB;}
```

Comment: i do not want to mix the css in my script. i want to keep it sep. this is not a good practice. thanks for the input but i am want to keep css sep in the css file

Comment: @virtualgod you have set `.tiles:hover { background-color: #0047AB;` which causes the problem the color cyan is set but on hover blue color is set

Comment: debin that seems to be the problem. this is working when i remove the hover effect. Two questions still:
1. how do i keep the hover effect? Rememer i do not want the css manipulation directly in jqueyr script
2. I verified your suggestoin and that seems to be the problem, but even then if i directly change the background color using the css thing in jquery script then it still works. why is that then?

Comment: . can you clear my last doubt?
with the above buggy code that I had, it is now clear that the bug was in my css file due to hover effect kicking in. This is a great catch. However, I still am failing to understand one last thing. Even with my original buggy code, and the jquery code as it, if I was adding one extra line :$(this).css('background-color', '0047AB');, then the issue was not happening. But I did not want to modify css in the jqyer. What I still don't get is that why the buggy CSS hover code was not kicking in if I was manipulating the css in the jquery script. Any tohughts?

Comment: accept it as an answer if it helps you so that other can refer this

Comment: i accepted the ans, i can message you over some chat if you share your email id. I am stil not getting the concept that inline has highest priority when i set it using jquery

Comment: I get it. inline css is what goes in the tag and that has higher priority than internal, external both. thanks a lot man! you are charmer

Comment: glad it could help..sorry buddy ..if you have any problem post here I will help you if I can:)

Comment: i am getting greedy. I can post a sep Q. I want to align the text say to bottom left, or bottom right in my tile but not able to do so either. the text is inside the span and span is inside the div

Comment: should post a sep Q or mix it with this?

Comment: post a separate question if you have a doubt

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 $(function() {
   $('body').on('mousedown', '.tiles', function(event) {
     console.log("tile clicked")
     $(".activeTile").removeClass("activeTile");
       $(this).toggleClass("activeTile");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
​$(document).on('click', '.tiles', function(e) {
       //code    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Event handler should be **[click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** and you should be doing **[Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**, it allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.tiles', function() {
    $(".activeTile").removeClass("activeTile");
    $(this).addClass("activeTile");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact click event..

```
$(".tiles").click(function(){
    $(".tiles").removeClass("activeTile");
    $(this).toggleClass("activeTile");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tiles { color: white; width: 120px; height: 120px; /*margin: 0 auto;*/
background-color: #3399CC; padding: 10px; position: relative; border: 2px solid #2F4F4F; transition: all 0.5s ease; /*text-align: center;*/
vertical-align: middle; line-height: 13; font-weight: bold; }
.activeTile { background-color: cyan; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".tiles").on('click',function() {
console.log("tile clicked");
$(".activeTile").removeClass("activeTile");
$(this).toggleClass("activeTile");
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><div class="tiles">first div</div></td>
<td><div class="tiles">second div</div></td>
<td><div class="tiles">third div</div></td>
<td><div class="tiles">fourth div</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but my tiles are in a table and table in a div. so why is that not working? is it some jquery related thing that i have to learn more for this to work? can u explain? the above code works but it won;t solve my purpose

Comment: pls check now. i have add table in a div :)

Comment: debin suggested that it is the hover property my css file that is causing it. i partly agree with him. when i remove the hover, things work. but now the 2 questions are
1. how do i change the hover color? add hoverTileClass like custom class using jquery again?
2. if i direclty manipulate the css via jquery and still leave the hover in css file why does it work? can u share ur email id?

Comment: my emial id "narender.lodhi4us@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tiles').on('click', function (e) {
  $('.activeTile').removeClass('activeTile');
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('activeTile');
});
```

Also, please add some more information on the surrounding HTML or environment to narrow the issue down because the click function might not be the issue here.